# DJANGO: Static files not loading in live server (but loads locally)?

Tags: python, css, django, django-views, django-templates

**Django website (django version 1.11.29) not loading the css and js scripts from static folder on the live server. But loads locally. Any ideas?**

The to css seems to be correct but does not go to the css style sheet itself.

**link to css on localhost host:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/website/login/login-style.css">
```

**link to css on live server:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/website/login/login-style.css">
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# other code...

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
#updated
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)
```

login.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/login/login-style.css' %}">
```

static folder structure:

```
blah\project\website\static\website\login
```

**Update:**
I realise I need to copy all files to root static folder for production via `python manage.py collectstatic`.

However still not loading. Am I missing a step? updated settings.py

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production. It is expected to be done by a webserver.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#deployment

Comment: collectstatic only collects all static files into the dir declared on 'STATIC_ROOT'. You still have to tell your server the URL to your static files. On pythonanywhere, for instance you have to configure URL and PATH properly on your web app settings.

Comment: Where are you deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on django documents, you should use nginx or other web servers to serve static files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#deployment

if you don't want to serve via web servers you could use whiteNoise:

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

on `urls.py` add this line to urlpatterns  : `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
so it will look like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
               
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and import static : `from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Answer (score -1):

Django take static files from "app/static/app/style.css" only on development server. When we deploy on a real server it takes from assets folder.